# Синхронизация иерархической структуры

Tags: алгоритм, структуры, графы, структуры-данных, синхронизация

Существует иерархическая структура данных, которая периодически обновляется на основе выгрузки из внешнего источника. Выгрузка может быть полная или по одному конкретному узлу.

Каждый узел имеет булевский аттрибут 'hidden', который приходит в выгрузке. Также узел имеет некий контент, который может быть и пустым. Также каждый узел имеет булевский аттрибут 'empty', который нужно заново рассчитать в момент синхронизации.

Аттрибут empty должен быть выставлен true, если узел соответствует всем условиям:

- Узел имеет пустой контент
- Узел не имеет не-empty и не-hidden потомков

В выгрузке потомки идут гарантированно после своих родителей, поэтому раньше определение empty осуществлялось так:

Программа проходит последовательно по выгрузке, каждый узел добавляет в базу или обновляет, если он там уже есть. Смотрит в выгрузке, пустой ли у него контент. Делает выборку в своей базе непосредственных потомков этого узла, которые не empty и не hidden. На основе этого выставляет значение empty.

После этого программа последовательно проходит вверх по цепочке родителей этого узла и проделывает для них ту же процедуру. Это нужно потому, что в пока не отработанной части выгрузки будет информация о потомках, и если обновился их список или их значения empty и hidden, то это может сделать невалидным значение empty родителя, и его нужно пересчитать.

Знаю, что алгоритм выглядит неоптимальным, но его писал не я.

Сейчас пришла задача: сделать так, чтобы узёл могли являться как бы алиасом (ссылкой) на другой узел. Это нужно для реализации параллельной иерархии.

Соответственно, в расчёте empty нужно учитывать, что узел должен быть не-empty, если ссылается на не-empty узел. Проблема в том, что в выгрузке алиас может присутствовать как раньше, так и позже того узла, на который он ссылается.

Как правильнее всего реализовать такую структуру с учётом описанных требований?

UPD: В качестве БД используется PosgreSQL через sqlalchemy. Соответственно, вся работа по синхронизации выполняется питоновским скриптом.

Таблица узлов имеет поля: id, parent_id, link_id, hidden, empty и ещё несколько полей, которые никак не участвуют в данной задаче.

parent_id и link_id - это id из этой же таблицы.

Ещё есть таблица с контентом, из которой для каждого узла берётся некоторое количество элементов.

Comment: В момент пересчета статуса узла найти все ссылки на него и так же их обновить. Из выгрузки игнорировать ссылки если они уже есть в БД в том же виде как пришли или создавать, если их еще нет. И может сначала загрузить все статусы, а потом сделать единый пересчет всех родителей в иерархии. для этого возможно добавить признак changed на узлы, что бы не проводить пересчет всего дерева.

Comment: И если бы вы указали какая именно БД и какова ее структура (с учетом линков) можно было бы придумать конкретное решение под нее. Хотя моя идея остается такой что не надо ничего вычислять в момент синхронизации конкретного элемента. Сначала все грузим, выставляя changed если не наследованное значение empty для узла изменилось и после этого пробегаем по дереву снизу вверх и обновляем статусы, начиная с записей с changed, параллельно (или по завршении, если уложиться в один запрос) сбрасывая этот статус

Comment: @Mike, добавил информацию о структуре.

Comment: "_и еще несколько полей_" - я думаю можно для наглядности считать наличие одного поля content на основе которого вычислять empty. Кстати, при загрузке может выяснится, что какого то узла нет и при этом удалится он и все ссылки на него ? И если да, то как вы отслеживаете этот факт ?

Comment: И да, вам как больше нравится, пересчитывать часть ветвей на основе некоторых changed или разом все дерево ? Если обычно меняется только небольшая честь то changed конечно удобен. но его надо где то хранить. И это можно было бы делать в той же таблице и менять при том же update что меняет content или в отдельной таблице вести список id изменившихся записей, тогда помимо основного update понадобится еще insert в эту таблицу, но зато после работы ее можно очистить и признак используемый только при обновлении не будет висеть в основной таблице

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за комментарии, буду думать. То, что изменившиеся поля можно помечать флагом или собирать в отдельную таблицу - очень интересный вариант. Если хотите, вы можете вынести их в ответ, плюс я прямо сейчас поставлю, и если через пару дней никто ничего лучше не предложит, то отмечу как решение.

Comment: Вы думаете я на этом остановлюсь ? ;) мне стало интересно ... postgresql какой версии ? И я так понял вам идея с changed понравилась, значит пересчет всего дерева видимо слишком ресурсоемок из за его объема, хотя запрос полного пересчета ожидается более простым...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем в таблицу с деревом поле `changed` типа `int`. На колонку строим partial index: `create index tree_change on tree(changed) where changed is not null`. При загрузке данных извне устанавливаем `changed=1` для всех записей *непосредственно в которых* содержимое или hidden изменились таким образом, что поле `empty` должно изменится. Иерархию записей на данном этапе вообще не рассматриваем. У всех новых записей так же ставим `changed=1`.

По завершении загрузки внешних данных выполняем такой запрос:

```
with recursive Q(id, parent_id, link_id, changed) as(
  select id, parent_id, link_id, changed from tree where changed=1
 union all
  select t.id, t.parent_id, t.link_id, Q.changed+1
    from Q, tree t where t.id=Q.parent_id or t.link_id=Q.id
)
UPDATE tree AS t
   SET changed = n.changed
  FROM (
    select id, max(changed) changed
      from Q where changed>1
     group by id
  ) n
 WHERE t.id = n.id;
```

Он выставляет у всех родительских по иерархии записей (а так же у записей для которых `link_id` указывает на изменяющиеся) `changed` на 1 больше, чем у дочерних. Фактически это число переходов в дереве от измененного узла до данного родительского. В случае если один и тот же узел имеет разное расстояние от нескольких изменившихся дочерних элементов берется максимальное из них.

Таким образом changed будет выставлен у всех узлов, которые зависят (по иерархии) от изменившихся.

После чего в цикле, пока update изменил хотя бы одну запись выполняем такой запрос:

```
update tree t
   set empty=(case when content is not null then 0
              else (select coalesce(min(t1.empty::int),1)
                      from tree t1
                     where t1.parent_id=t.id or t1.id=t.link_id)
             end)::boolean,
       changed=NULL
 where changed=$N
```

Где `$N` порядковый номер итерации цикла от 1 до максимального `changed` полученного после первого запроса (непосредственно получать максимум не имеет смысла, сам факт изменения записей говорит о том, что такой номер еще был).

Каждый запрос в цикле рассчитывает empty у узла дерева исходя из состояния самого узла (в первую очередь) и всех его непосредственных детей (если у самого узла не заполнено content). Углубляться по иерархии не надо, так как обновление родителей будет происходить только после того, как были пересчитаны все дети (потому как у детей заведомо меньший `changed`).

Значения поля `hidden` я не учитывал, добавьте по своему вкусу в логику вычисления статуса во второй запрос.